robust authentification with flutter
Now, I am developing a Flutter application with Firebase as the database for my final project. Initially, I used simple authentication with Firebase, but my professor told me that I should use a more robust authentication, preferably something open source. I didn't quite understand what she meant. Is there something like that which could help me?

Usually, I only use Firebase authentication.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
